# Mobile antivirus app classifies my app as a "potentially unwanted program"

Tags: android, permissions, malware, antivirus

AVG Antivirus says that my app is a potentially unwanted program. On reading more, it says that:

> "No potential malware has been detected for this android app for the
>   last 7 days. However, active adware was detected".

What can be the probable reasons for this?

Snippets of the Manifest:

```html
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" />
```

Comment: maybe your app is named similar to an adware programm....you can´t do anything against something like this, maybe contact AVG...

Comment: @Opiatefuchs I googled the name, nothing similar there. Any other possibilities?